# is there any way to filter RDD which contains specific pattern

Tags: java, apache-spark

In below code i am filtering log which contains 404 HTTP status code but now if i want to filter that log which contains 400-405 any of the HTTP status code.

```
JavaRDD<String> IPList = sc.textFile("/home/bhaumik/Documents/access_log", 1)
        .filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public Boolean call(String v1) throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return v1.contains(" 404 ");
            }
        });
```

So is there any option to do it?

Given is my sample log records

```
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:20:55:43 -0800] "GET /mailman/listinfo/hs_support HTTP/1.1" 200 6294
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:20:56:56 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/TWiki/WebTopicList HTTP/1.1" 200 14070
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:20:58:27 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/attach/TWiki/WebPreferences HTTP/1.1" 401 12846
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:21:03:48 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/TWiki/TWikiFAQ HTTP/1.1" 200 12050
64.242.88.10 - - [07/Mar/2004:21:06:05 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/oops/TWiki/DefaultPlugin?template=oopsmore&param1=1.5&param2=1.5 HTTP/1.1" 200 11281
```

Comment: Adding a sample of the log would help in adding a more correct answer.

Comment: You can see my updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way would be:

```
return v1.contains(" 400 ")||v1.contains(" 401 ")||v1.contains(" 402 ");
```

But that way you may get false positives when the size of the file is 400...405

One alternative may be:

```
String[] parts = v1.split(" ");
return parts[parts.length - 2].matches("40[0-5]");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The regex that Justin used is more elegant. I changed my answer to use the regex on the block of the logs that contains the HTTP code.

Answer (score 2):

I think a regex works here:

```
return v1.matches(".*40[0-5].*")
```

This matches anything with a string that contains 400-405. This also means that if 400 is in the log in another fashion it will pick it up. You might want to split on delimiters and then cast to an `Int` and do a proper check.